# Trying to find the indexOf a string from an ArrayList filled with strings from hashtable, only returning -1

Tags: java

I am trying to get the indexOf of a specific string from an ArrayList but the string is not matching when doing the check.  I am filling the StringList from hashtable with the code below.

```
stringList = new ArrayList<String>

Set st = hashtable.keySet();
Iterator itr = st.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
  stringList.add(((String)itr.next()).trim());
}
```

The string I am trying to get from the stringList is input by the user, the string is generally in the form of “! Xxxx ##:##:## xx” if that makes a difference.  I know the string match in the fact that I test it visually by printing out the stringList. So I figure it is something similar to the == and .equals().

I tested also by filling the stringList with a specific String from the hashtable and using the code below and it always returns false.

```
String keyString = "! Xxxx ##:##:## xx";
if(stringList.get(0).equals(keyString))
   System.out.println("true");
System.out.println("false");
```

So I am trying to figure out how to get the code below to work

```
stringList.indexOf(keyString)
```

because it only returns -1 which it should, as it is not seeing the strings are equal. What am I doing wrong that is preventing the output I am looking for, which would be the correct index that I think it should be returning since I am typing exactly what is being print out by stringList. Like I said before, I thought it was an issue with .equals() but from what I can tell indexOf uses .equals() when looking for the index as well as seeing the results from me testing .equals() myself.

Comment: Shouldn't `stringList().indexOf(keyString)` be `stringList.indexOf(keyString)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, it is not that way in my code, edited post to reflect this change. Thank you.

Comment: Does the String you are looking for really look like `"! Xxxx ##:##:## xx"` or is it somethis like `"! abcd 12:34:56 ef"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon says, there's probably a difference in the actual characters of the two strings, that doesn't appear visually.

Pass the two Strings that are supposed to be equal to the following method to know where the problem is:

```
public void dumpString(String s) {
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Length: " + s.length());
    System.out.print("Chars: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print((int) s.charAt(i));
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Both you and @Jon were spot on and before I could type out a quick test for what Jon suggested, that was my problem and this showed me exactly what char I was missing. It came back on how I was parsing the input from the user. Duh! Wish I would posted the code for how I was dealing with the input as well because  you guys would have spotted instantaneously I am sure! Thanks so much guys, I guess sometimes I should just walk away and take a break when I overlook those types of things. :) Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2):

> I know the string match in the fact that I test it visually by printing out the stringList.

That's probably the problem. There can be all kinds of subtle ways in which strings *aren't* actually equal, which don't show up by casual inspection. For example, if you have trailing Unicode NULL characters (U+0000) those probably wouldn't show up, and there are other non-printing characters too.

I suggest you iterate over `stringList` printing out the *length* of the string as well as the contents - then print the length of `keyString` too.

Also note that this code:

```
String keyString = "! Xxxx ##:##:## xx";
if(stringList.get(0).equals(keyString))
   System.out.println("true");
System.out.println("false");
```

... will *always* print `false` (assuming there's no exception). It may *also* print `true`, of course - but you're *unconditionally* printing `false`. It would be much simpler to just write:

```
String keyString = "! Xxxx ##:##:## xx";
System.out.println(stringList.get(0).equals(keyString));
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing so I did try .trim() to both the string being put into the ArrayList and the string being input by user and .equal() nor == would come back as true. Not sure if .trim() would really take care of that problem but I did try it

Comment: @NotIllogical: If `equals()` returns false, then the strings simply aren't equal. I didn't suggest trimming - I suggested printing out the lengths. You might also want to print out the UTF-16 code unit value (as an int) for each character in the string, to see whether there are two characters which *looks* the same but aren't.

Comment: I see that, and like I said not sure if it would make a difference so I stated what I had tried. Since I was not sure if trimming would take off trailing Unicode NULL characters being that I am relatively new to programming in general. Wouldn't trimming take care of issues like that? Printing out the lengths is a great idea though and I will try it, also thank you for pointing out the conditionals. Love that I can learn something that I was not even going for! :)

Comment: @NotIllogical: I don't honestly remember whether `trim()` will deal with Unicode NULL values. I'm sure there are plenty of non-printing characters that it *wouldn't* trim though.

Answer (score 1):

The string you are adding to your stung list is trimmed so any trailing or leading spaces will be removed. If the initial strings have spaces that could be your problem. Try removing the .trim() and see if that helps.